# How do you clear a determinate progress bar for reuse?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar

I have an Activity with a button that starts a long running task. I perform the task using an AsyncTask and display a determinate ProgressBar that is updated as the task progresses. Everything works fine the first time the task is run, but on subsequent runs the dialog appears, but is already at 100% and 100/100. I'm overriding both onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog in my Activity. I presumed that using setProgress(0) would reset the dialog, but this isn't working. I use showDialog in the AsyncTask's onPreExecute method and dismissDialog in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute. The only way I've been able to get the dialog to reset is by using removeDialog in onPostExecute, but I would rather not recreate the dialog as I'm going to be reusing several times. The relevant code is below. This is on API level 10.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProtoBufSerializationTestActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Testing...");
            return progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            ProgressDialog tmp = (ProgressDialog)dialog;
            tmp.setProgress(0);
            tmp.setSecondaryProgress(0);
            return;
        default:
            Log.e("test", "Unknown dialog requested");
    }
}

private class SerializationTestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        long accumulator = 0;
        int totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            final long start = System.nanoTime();
            //code to be timed
            final long end = System.nanoTime();
            accumulator += end - start;
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                publishProgress(i);
            }
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        results.setText(String.format("Serialized Message 10000 times.\nAverage time to serialize %.3fms", (double) aLong / 1e10));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }
```

**Edit** After taking @Arhimed's suggestion I ended up with the following code. It is much simpler. I could have used `DialogFragment`, but I don't think it is necessary in this case.

```
private class SerializationTestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProtoBufSerializationTestActivity.this, "Serialization Test", "Testing...", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        long accumulator = 0;
        int totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            final long start = System.nanoTime();
            //code to be timed
            final long end = System.nanoTime();
            accumulator += end - start;
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                publishProgress(i);
            }
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        results.setText(String.format("Serialized Message 10000 times.\nAverage time to serialize %.3fms", (double) aLong / 1e10));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to use `ProgressDialog` in that way. Your `AsyncTask` should create a new instance each time.

Comment: Why does Android bother with the callbacks and the caching then? Is it only for indeterminate ProgressDialogs? The Android dev guide does almost the same thing I'm doing http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog.

Comment: @volker238 I don't understand your comment. The callback is to update the progress dialog without holding up the UI thread.

Comment: The callbacks (`onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog`) work nice for `AlertDialogs`. However I encountered `ProgressDialog`s do not work this way - at least I was not able to reuse an instance of `ProgressDialog`, specifically indeterminate progress spinner did not animate the seconds time I show the same instance. So I always create a new instance of `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`. This way it works nice.

Comment: @BDFun I was talking about the onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog callbacks not the callbacks in AsyncTask.

Comment: @Arhimed Ok then I guess I'll just replace dismissDialog with removeDialog and get rid of the onPrepareDialog call back since it is useless.

Comment: BTW, your case just confirms that there is smth wrong with `onCreateDialog`/`onPrepareDialog` callbacks for `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: @volker238: then isn't it easier (increases code readability) to put the entire progress code inside of the AsyncTask? :)

Comment: @Arhimed Yeah I will refactor the code removing the callbacks and update my question with the new code later. I always try to be idiomatic in language/API and I was following the dev guides example. Another solution is to just replace dismissDialog with removeDialog and then a new ProgressDialog is created in showDialog.

Comment: @volker238: Also just a point to bear in mind - `onCreateDialog` and `onPrepareDialog` in `Activity` are deprecated. The API instructs to use `DialogFragment` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Arhimed is right and you can't do it but you can force progress bar to come to its zero state with 'dirty' way.For me the client wanted progress bar to zero its value no matter what,in case if user leave that activity,but in my case the progress was still there,and only was reseting from start.I had custom progress drawable and `setProgress` did not help me at all.So what i did was to call this method before actually setting the REAL drawable `setProgressDrawable(null)` this is dirty way clearing,but it do what you want,and afterwards just call same method with your own progressdrawable so it feels like it has been refreshed.Thats it..no other way you can achieve this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually setProgress(0) refreshes the display only if the progress is started.
So, you can force the refresh by calling onStart before setProgress, like this :

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    ProgressDialog progress = (ProgressDialog)dialog;
    progress.onStart();
    progress.setProgress(0);
}
```